# Sphinx search by 2 fields

Tags: search, sphinx

I have mysql table with 2 fields to search:

```
SELECT name, tag FROM table
```

I add this table to Sphinx and I need to search through this table next way:

First I show results matched first field - name
Then I need to show results matched second field - tag

All this results I need to show in one result

Answer (score 0):

In general ranking doesnt work like that, its difficult to explicitly sort like that.

But there is FieldWeights, which will get you pretty much the same result
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setfieldweights

(if using sphinxQL, there is a field_weights OPTION)

... just set a high weight for name, and a lower weight for tag, should mean name matches will get a bigger weight, and be shown first.